# AWS ECR enhanced scanning - Continuous scanning option: when is the registry scanned?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecr

Really basic question, but I can't seem to find it in the documentation. When continuous scanning is turned on, at what frequency and at which time the registry will be scanned? I've turned it on a couple of hours ago but it hasn't scanned yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuous scanning will be executed when a new vulnerability is received by AWS. I couldn't pinpoint when the initial scan happened. It took approximately a half day.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same issue and came across with this question. I will post the docs quote.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide//image-scanning.html?icmpid=docs_ecr_hp-registry-private

> As new vulnerabilities appear, the scan results are updated and Amazon Inspector emits an event to EventBridge to notify you.

Answer (score -1):

did you turn one the "Scan on push" option, go the Edit option end then enable that option, it will automatically scan your repo after each push.

if you go for manual scan it's generally trigger immediately.

please give a try

Comment: My question was focused on the continuous scanning option, not the scan on push option

Comment: then go with Enhanced scanning feature with filter option. please refer below ling for your reference.

"With enhanced scanning, you can choose which repositories are configured for automatic, continuous scanning and which are configured for scan on push. This is done by setting scan filters. "

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/image-scanning-enhanced.html